# Trying to convert a shapefile that seems to be using UTM coordinates to WGS84 in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, wgs84, utm

I've been trying to convert this polygon shapefile of historic Swedish parishes from UTM coords to lat/long and nothing seems to be working. I've tried defining projection, reprojecting, saving these new projections as new shapefiles and loading them to a new project, fixing geometries, extracting vertices and converting the csv file of coords to lat/long and the closest I can get is:

[image]

Comment: What are the origin and destination coordinate systems?

Comment: @BERA, looks like a question for you =)

Comment: I don't see the issue here. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: *Not working* is fairly vague, it covers everything from no output to workstations catching fire... From the image I can see your data is off location by quite a distance to the north northeast, are you *sure* the coordinates are UTM? I am assuming you mean WGS84/UTM when you say UTM, WGS84 didn't exist before 1984, being historic data the boundaries would be in a coordinate system that existed at that time, unless the data has already been projected from the historic coordinates into WGS84 UTM there needs to be a geographic transformation applied.